# Missing files warning

Tags: xcode

I have several warnings like that: "filename is missing from working copy" (xCode 8 beta 6).

The problem is these files are not missing, I didn't delete them, they're here, and xCode is able to open them.

Should I be worried about these warnings? How could I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem. What worked for me was the following:

1. `git add` and `commit` all the files you want to use going forward
2. clean the project
3. run `git log` and get the last commit id
4. run `git reset --hard <commit id>`
5. Build in Xcode